# Copy data from one table to another but adding 2nd WHERE clause won't insert data

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have two tables.  When A user clicks a button, it will copy data from table 1 to table 2 where the doesn't already exist in table 2.

I had the query working just fine, until I added a new column in the first table named "onsite" - which is either set to yes, or it is NULL.

Here is the query I've tried.  It no longer inserts ANY data to the past_bidder table (table 2)

```
$copybidderquery = "INSERT INTO past_bidders(bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created) 
SELECT bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created 
FROM bidders 
WHERE (bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress) 
NOT IN (SELECT bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress FROM past_bidders) 
AND onsite != 'yes'";
```

I've also tried moving the where onsite != 'yes' to right after "WHERE" and it still does the same thing.

```
$copybidderquery = "INSERT INTO past_bidders(bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created) 
SELECT bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created 
FROM bidders 
WHERE onsite != 'yes'
AND (bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress) 
NOT IN (SELECT bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress FROM past_bidders)";
```

As stated, this query works just fine without the "onsite != 'yes'" line.

I think it's just some little syntax error I'm overlooking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the issue is NULL values in `onsite`. (That's just a guess, since we aren't seeing any example data, or the expected output.) We do know that `onsite != 'yes'` comparison will return NULL whenever `onsite` is NULL. If you want to include rows where `onsite` is NULL, you need to write the condition differently.  As just one example, **`NOT ( onsite <=> 'yes')`**, but there are other patterns that will return an equivalent result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO past_bidders(bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created) 
SELECT bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created 
FROM bidders 
WHERE  onsite is NULL AND (bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress) 
NOT IN (SELECT bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress FROM past_bidders) 
;
```

Check following example when you say not equal to something it will not return the null values

```
mysql> select * from calls;
+----+------------+---------+
| id | date       | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2016-06-22 |       1 |
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |
|  5 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |
|  6 | 2016-06-23 |       1 |
|  7 | 2016-06-23 |    NULL |
+----+------------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from calls where user_id!=1;
+----+------------+---------+
| id | date       | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  4 | 2016-06-23 |       2 |
+----+------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from calls where user_id is null;
+----+------------+---------+
| id | date       | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  2 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  3 | 2016-06-22 |    NULL |
|  7 | 2016-06-23 |    NULL |
+----+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

could be there are hidden char or the value is not 'yes' or you should check for not null too

```
$copybidderquery = "INSERT INTO past_bidders(bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created) 
                                  SELECT bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created 
                FROM bidders 
                WHERE (bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress) 
                NOT IN (SELECT bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress FROM past_bidders) 
                AND trim(lower(onsite) )!= 'yes';
```

Comment: The `onsite is not null` is redundant. The predicate immediately before that cannot evaluate to TRUE if `onsite` is null.

Answer (score 1):

`!=` returns `NULL` when either value is `NULL`.  You have two choices:

```
SELECT bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created 
FROM bidders 
WHERE (bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress) NOT IN
          (SELECT bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress
           FROM past_bidders
          ) AND
      onsite is null;
```

Or, use the `NULL` safe equality:

```
SELECT bidnum, bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress, bidtaxexempt, bidtaxid, date_created 
FROM bidders 
WHERE (bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress) NOT IN
          (SELECT bidfname, bidlname, bidphnum, bidlicense, bidaddress
           FROM past_bidders
          ) AND
      (NOT onsite <=> 'yes');
```

Comment: I was not aware of the <=> either.  I needed to use "is null" instead of is not null.  But it was definitely what was going on. If you want to change it to is not null I will accept your answer. Thank you so much